# Add inputs, multiply by price, display total

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, math

I'm trying to create a very simple PHP form for an online t-shirt order form. I have pretty much everything down, except the final calculations. I would like the sizes to add up, multiply by the price (lets say $10.00), then display the total. At the moment it's only displaying the total quantity.

I know I'm missing the multiplication step, but everything I tried failed. If you can give me some sort of direction, that would be great. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/hSxkW/14/

Form:

```
<div>
<input name=S />
<input name=M />
<input name=L />
<input name=XL />
<input name=XXL />
<input name=XXXL /><br>
Total: $<span class=size></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input[name=S], input[name=M], input[name=L], input[name=XL], input[name=XXL], input[name=XXXL]').keyup(function() {
    var divParent = $(this).closest('div');
    var S = $('input[name=S]', divParent).val()-0;
    var M = $('input[name=M]', divParent).val()-0;
    var L = $('input[name=L]', divParent).val()-0;;
    var XL = $('input[name=XL]', divParent).val()-0;
    var XXL = $('input[name=XXL]', divParent).val()-0;
    var XXXL = $('input[name=XXXL]', divParent).val()-0;
    if (S >= 0 && M >= 0 && L >= 0 && XL >= 0 && XXL >= 0 && XXXL >= 0)
        $('span.size', divParent).text(S+M+L+XL+XXL+XXXL);
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this question is tagged with `PHP`.

Comment: Where is the "price" by which you want to multiply defined?

Comment: My fault - changed the tag to JS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty basic to me.

Change:

```
if (S >= 0 && M >= 0 && L >= 0 && XL >= 0 && XXL >= 0 && XXXL >= 0) $('span.size', divParent).text(S+M+L+XL+XXL+XXXL);
```

to:

```
if (S >= 0 && M >= 0 && L >= 0 && XL >= 0 && XXL >= 0 && XXXL >= 0) $('span.size', divParent).text(10*(S + M + L + XL + XXL + XXXL));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hSxkW/16/)**

Comment: Figures that I would over-think it. Thank you much

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
<div id="orderContainer">
   <input data-price="{priceS}" data-oldprice="0" name=S />
   <input data-price="{priceM}" data-oldprice="0" name=M />
   <input data-price="{priceL}" data-oldprice="0" name=L />
   <input data-price="{priceXL}" data-oldprice="0" name=XL />
   <input data-price="{priceXXL}" data-oldprice="0" name=XXL />
   <input data-price="{priceXXXL}" data-oldprice="0" name=XXXL /><br>
   Total: $<span class="size">0</span>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(function($){
       var container = $("#orderContainer");
       container.find("input").keyup(function(){
           var item = $(this);
           var totalspan = container.find("span.size");
           var price = parseInt(item.data("price"))*parseInt(item.val());
           var oldprice = parseInt(item.data("price"))*parseInt(item.data("oldprice"));
           var totalprice = parseInt(totalspan.html());
           item.data("oldprice", price);
           totalspan.html(totalprice-oldprice+price);
       });
    });
</script>
```

how you add prices to inputs - entirely up to you.